# How to write razor query to display two fields side by side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I am dynamically generating the fields using a `foreach` loop. I have several conditions on rendering those fields. There is one condition where on it being true, there are two fields that should be rendered side by side on the same row.
I tried every possible approach but it isn't getting rendered as I want. I can't use `<div class="form-group">` of as it will display the fields on separate lines. 
So, how should I write the razor query combined with bootstrap's code such that I have two fields side by side. Here is my current code:

```
@foreach (var d in data)
{
    if (Condition1)
    {
        <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                Text 1
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">

                @Html.TextBox("Box1")

            </div>

        </div>
    }
    else if(Condition 2)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">
                Text 2
            </label>

            <div class="col-sm-8">

                @Html.TextBox("Box2")

            </div>
        </div>
    }

     else if(Condition3)
     {
        <form class="form-inline">
            <label class="required col-sm-3 control-label">
                @*Horsepower and RPM*@
            </label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                @{
                    @Html.TextBox("Box2")
                }
            </div>
        </form>       
     }
}
```

Condition 3 is where I want to render those 2 fields
This is my current state:
[check position of horsepower or rpm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxuGQ.png)

Comment: you need to split your data into two columns , what you have is a foreach loop which inside this loop you are adding `form-group`, its trivial to show each field on separate line.

Comment: yes but how to do that using razor i.e inside the ` else if` condition

Comment: check my code below , I used `@:` in order to write Html  `div`

Answer (score 0):

put the fields next to each other using bootstrap row. statement 3 can for example hold both col-md-6 div tags

```
    <div class="row">

    @if(statement1) {
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">form 1</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
   }
    @if(statement2) {
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="">form 2</label>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div
  }
```

http://jsbin.com/nalexuredo/edit?html,output

Comment: That is the problem, it gets rendered one below the other and not side by side using `if` condition

Comment: Thanks for the edit.. Can you please show how it's done for `else if`? Because writing `else if` after `<div class = "row">` is not accepting..

Answer (score 0):

You can do the follow

1. convert your `foreach` to `for` with `index`
2. check if the `index%2==0` is true, this means you have to go on new line but here you have two options

   - The loop in the beginning => `index is equal 0`  call it A: you need to add `form-group`
   - The loop not in the beginning => `index >0` call it B: you need to close the previous `div` and to add new `form-group`

The Logic

```
 if(index%2 ==0)
    {
        if(index>0) // works with the case B
        {
            </div>
        }
        <div class="form-group">
    }
    ....
```

3. finally once you go out the for loop you need to add the `</div>`

Here a code sample:

**The Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var list = new List<Data>()
            {
                new Data{Value="Val 1"},
                new Data{Value="Val 2"},
                new Data{Value="Val 3"},
                new Data{Value="Val 4"},
                new Data{Value="Val 5"},
                new Data{Value="Val 6"},
                new Data{Value="Val 7"}
            };
            return View(list);
        }


    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**The View CSHTML**

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Controllers.Data>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


@for (var index = 0; index < Model.Count; index++)
{
    if (index % 2 == 0)
    {
        if (index > 0)
        {
            @:</div>
        }
        @:<div class="row">
    }
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Model[index].Value @* here you can add whatever you want to represent your code*@
    </div>
}
@if (Model.Count > 0)
{
    @:</div>
}
```

**Note:** If you want for example to show 3 columns per line => use `index%3` and `class="col-md-4"` and so on.

Hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Sir, but please include `else if` condition after the html or bootstrap code eg `<div class = "row">`